# Server slow with many idle workers

Tags: apache-2.4, wordpress

Yesterday, I notice my WP Dashboard is a little slow compared with normal. So I check my Apache status, and find there are only 7 requests are being served, with remaining 193 idle workers. And the server load is also low(0.10, 0.16, 0.24), considering my server has 32 CPUs.

So why there will be such slow? Is it normal with so many idle workers?

Comment: WordPress performance strongly depends on the database performance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)